# Is it possible to specify the type of the data context for a Style?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF application that is using styles and templates to dynamically build a ribbon menu, here are the relevant snippets:

```
<RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" Header="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"/>

<Style TargetType="RibbonGroup" x:Key="GroupStyle">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Controls}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RibbonButtonTemplate}"/>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="RibbonButtonTemplate" DataType="{x:Type enums:RibbonControlConfig}">
    <RibbonButton Label="{Binding Header}" LargeImageSource="{Binding Image}" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

So now Resharper is complaining about the bindings within the GroupStyle since they are actually elements of a child property of the view model, as can be seen by the `ItemSource` binding on the RibbonTab.

This does of course function just fine, I would just prefer to have both no complaints from ReSharper and access to accurate Intellisense, so is there anyway to tell the style what it's context is?

Side note: I did first try to do this setup by using nested data templates but I wasn't able to get anything passed the first level template to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to specify the `DataContext` type in a style. In general, you shouldn't use bindings in a style anyway, because a style is about appearance, not about data. It's especially important to follow this rule if you plan to make your control reusable: you can't make assumptions about what it will be bound to.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, I will investigate taking a template approach later when I don't have more pressing functionality to be writing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can specify the type of the `DataContext` of the view to which you intend to apply a style. This is necessary in order to enjoy type safety, auto-completion, and to write XAML that is free from ReSharper warnings.

There are two ways that I know of, for specifying the type of the `DataContext` in a style; the bad way and the good way.

##### The bad way:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyView}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance MyViewModel}">
    ...
```

This looks okay, and it initially appears to work, but it is a very bad idea because if you use it, then the XAML Hot Reload feature will start silently failing without giving you the slightest hint as to why it is failing. For more information, see this post on my blog: [michael.gr - The Trouble with XAML Hot Reload in WPF](https://blog.michael.gr/2023/06/the-trouble-with-xaml-hot-reload-in-wpf.html)

##### The good way:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyView}">
    <d:Style.DataContext>
        <x:Type Type="MyViewModel" />
    </d:Style.DataContext>
    ...
```

This one just works.